# How to get a custom collection based on a data that is most repeated (from top to bottom))

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a table like this:

[image]

Basically this table is named `favourite_products` and contains product ids that are added as favourite for users.

Now I wanted to get a collection of most added product from this table.

So in this case, a product with an id of **10** would be on top of the collection.

But I don't know how to get this collection ordering by from most repeated product id (prd_id)...

Here is the Model:

```
class FavouriteProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'favourite_products';
    protected $fillable = ['usr_id','prd_id'];
    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usr_id');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'prd_id');
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1:**

`Product.php` Model:

```
public function favouritees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favourite_products', 'prd_id', 'usr_id');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have relation in ```Product``` model for  ```FavouriteProduct``` table ?

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai Yes I do have the relation in `Product` Model. I just added an **Update**.  It would be best if you could answer this question with the relationship way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code solve your problem:

```
$most_liked_products = DB::table('favourite_products')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(prd_id) as total'), id)
    ->groupBy('total')
    ->orderByDesc('total')
    ->get();
```

Please try it and give your feedback

Comment: The eloquent way is better

Comment: Only change DB::Table('favorite_products') to your model. I think count is not possible without DB::raw

Answer (score 1):

try use this

```
public function example()
{
    $data=FavouriteProduct::orderBy('prd_id', 'ASC')->get();
    dd($data);
}
```

Comment: Without ```groupby``` statment how can you determine how many record for each product is favourited.